# Gremlin Python - Add unknown number of properties to edge on edge creation if edge does not exist

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

The query should to the following:

- If an edge between two vertices exists: return the edge
- else: Create the edge, set properties from a dict and return the edge.

The following works if `traversal` is a pristine traversal.
If `traversal` already contains some other steps (e.g. creation of a vertex) 
it crashes with below error.

```
properties = {"p1": "p1_value", "p2": "p2_value"}

traversal.V().inject(properties).as_(props_label).
V().has("uuid",from_uuid).as_(from_label).
V().has("uuid",to_uuid).as_(to_label).
coalesce(inE(edge_label).where(outV().
as_(from_label)),addE(edge_label).
from_(from_label).as_(e_label).select(props_label).
unfold().as_(kv_label).select(e_label).
property(select(kv_label).by(Column.keys),select(kv_label).by(Column.values))).iterate()
```

```
gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 500: The provided object does not have accessible keys: class org.janusgraph.graphdb.vertices.StandardVertex
```

If I `iterate()` the traversal before `injecting`, it works. But I would like to avoid the iterate for performance reasons.

Any ideas?

**edit:**

I did some more testing. Adding the vertices beforehand works.
Adding them in the same query does not.

This works:

```
gremlin> g.addV("TestType").property("name", "1")
==>v[2302192]
gremlin> g.addV("TestType").property("name", "2")
==>v[2326704]
gremlin> g.inject(["p1": "v1", "p2": "v2"]).unfold().as("props").V(2302192).as("from").V(2326704).as("to").coalesce(inE("DEPENDS_ON").where(outV().as("from")), addE("DEPENDS_ON").from("from").property(select("props").by(keys), select("props").by(values)))
==>e[187by-1dcds-1lh-1dvao][2302192-DEPENDS_ON->2326704]
==>e[187by-1dcds-1lh-1dvao][2302192-DEPENDS_ON->2326704]
```

This fails:

```
gremlin> g.addV("TestType").property("name", "1").addV("TestType").property("name", "2").inject(["p1": "v1", "p2": "v2"]).unfold().as("props").V().has("name", "1").as("from").V().has("name", "2").as("to").coalesce(inE("DEPENDS_ON").where(outV().as("from")), addE("DEPENDS_ON").from("from").property(select("props").by(keys), select("props").by(values))).dedup()
The provided object does not have accessible keys: class org.janusgraph.graphdb.vertices.StandardVertex
```

Comment: I don't quite understand a few aspects of your question. Specifically, I'm not sure I know what you mean by a "pristine traversal" and I don't know what you mean by your last sentence about "iterate() ... before injecting" and the point about performance. If my answer below doesn't help you may need to clarify your question a bit further in relation to those points.

Comment: @stephenmallette 

This is part of a bigger project that tries to map python objects to vertices.
It adds multiple vertices and edges while parsing the object graph. 
The current implementation is super slow. My observation is that it gets a lot faster the less iterate() calls I have, i.e. the longer the gremlin query gets.

The `traversal` in my example above can either be new or it can already contain several addV() calls. In the later case injection breaks.

Comment: I think you're saying that you're combining multiple mutations into one traversal to try to improve performance by reducing the number of individual requests. Does simply adding `V()` in front of `inject()` cause the failure you're seeing? or do you have to explicitly include `addV()`? If so, how many is "several" - perhaps, just update your question with that specific traversal that causes the problem? by the way, a failing example in the Gremlin Console would be the easiest way to debug this issue.

Comment: @stephenmallette I updated the question with a specific example.

`addV()` causes the problem. `V()` works.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to create a reproducible condition in Gremlin Console. That almost always makes it easy to solve problems. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an initial point, you do not need the first `V` in your traversal. You just need to start with `inject()`. If you start with `V()` you end up executing the following steps for every vertex in the graph.

That said, I don't see a problem with your traversal and it works fine with TinkerGraph once I adapted it to the modern toy graph:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> properties = [p1: "p1_value", p2: "p2_value"]
==>p1=p1_value
==>p2=p2_value
gremlin> g.inject(properties).as('props_label').
......1>   V().has("name",'marko').as('from_label').
......2>   V().has("name",'josh').as('to_label').
......3>   coalesce(inE('knows').where(outV().as('from_label')),
......4>            addE('knows').from('from_label').as('e_label').select('props_label').
......5>              unfold().as('kv_label').select('e_label').
......6>              property(select('kv_label').by(Column.keys),
......7>                       select('kv_label').by(Column.values)))
==>e[8][1-knows->4]
gremlin> g.inject(properties).as('props_label').
......1>   V().has("name",'peter').as('from_label').
......2>   V().has("name",'vadas').as('to_label').
......3>   coalesce(inE('knows').where(outV().as('from_label')),
......4>            addE('knows').from('from_label').as('e_label').select('props_label').
......5>              unfold().as('kv_label').select('e_label').
......6>              property(select('kv_label').by(Column.keys),
......7>                       select('kv_label').by(Column.values)))
==>e[13][6-knows->2]
==>e[13][6-knows->2]
```

You may wish to `dedup()` results on this traversal as you will get one result for each property key in the map given its `unfold()` at line 5.

The error you're getting is a server-side error and I don't think an issue with gremlinpython. It points to a situation where `select('kv_label').by(Column.keys)` is trying to access a JanusGraph `StandardVertex` object. I can recreate that problem in TinkerGraph easily enough given your updated question:

```
gremlin> g.addV("TestType").property("name", "1").
......1>   addV("TestType").property("name", "2").
......2>   inject(["p1": "v1", "p2": "v2"]).
......3>   unfold().as("props").
......4>   V().has("name", "1").as("from").
......5>   V().has("name", "2").as("to").
......6>   coalesce(inE("DEPENDS_ON").where(outV().as("from")), 
......7>            addE("DEPENDS_ON").from("from").
......8>              property(select("props").by(keys), select("props").by(values))).dedup()
The provided object does not have accessible keys: class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerVertex
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]n
```

This is a very different traversal from your original question which is why I wasn't able to recreate it. You're expecting just key/value pairs from your `inject()` in the stream but it in fact has something else:

```
gremlin> g.addV("TestType").property("name", "1").
......1>   addV("TestType").property("name", "2").
......2>   inject(["p1": "v1", "p2": "v2"]).
......3>   unfold()
==>p1=v1
==>p2=v2
==>v[2]
```

When `v[2]` makes its way to `select("props").by(keys)` you get the exception I described. You can fix it by moving `inject()` to the start or using `withSideEffect()`

```
gremlin> g.inject(["p1": "v1", "p2": "v2"]).as('props').
......1>   addV("TestType").property("name", "1").
......2>   addV("TestType").property("name", "2").
......3>   V().has("name", "1").as("from").
......4>   V().has("name", "2").as("to").
......5>   coalesce(inE("DEPENDS_ON").where(outV().as("from")), 
......6>            addE("DEPENDS_ON").from("from").as('e').
......7>              select('props').
......8>              unfold().as('kv').
......9>              select('e').
.....10>              property(select("kv").by(keys), select("kv").by(values))).dedup()
==>e[4][0-DEPENDS_ON->2]
gremlin> g.withSideEffect('props', ["p1": "v1", "p2": "v2"]).
......1>   addV("TestType").property("name", "1").
......2>   addV("TestType").property("name", "2").
......3>   V().has("name", "1").as("from").
......4>   V().has("name", "2").as("to").
......5>   coalesce(inE("DEPENDS_ON").where(outV().as("from")), 
......6>            addE("DEPENDS_ON").from("from").as('e').
......7>              select('props').
......8>              unfold().as('kv').
......9>              select('e').
.....10>              property(select("kv").by(keys), select("kv").by(values))).dedup()
==>e[4][0-DEPENDS_ON->2]
```

I'm not sure which is more intuitive. I tend to prefer `inject()` when I need something to start the traversal, but you have `addV()` to put objects in the start, so `inject()` seems clumsy there especially since `addV()` just replaces the `Map` its given. In this case, I think using `withSideEffect()` more explicitly tells someone reading this what the intent is.

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference for anybody who might stumble upon this in the future.
I found a solution that is much simpler using an anonymous traversal instead of injection:

```
properties = {"some key": "some value", "etc": "bla"}

# prepare the add vertex sub traversal
add_vertex_traversal = addV(label)
for k, v in properties.items():
    add_vertex_traversal = add_vertex_traversal.property(k, v)

g.V().has('some_prop', "some_value").fold().coalesce(unfold(),add_vertex_traversal))
```